# Ajax toolkit with public site

Tags: ajax-toolkit

Can I use Ajax toolkit with a public VF page?
I want to insert an object into the DB when a user submit's a form.
When I try it it gives me a "Refused to set unsafe header "User-Agent" error with an Invalid Session message.

Can I use Ajax toolkit with a public VF page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Unsafe Header" is just a warning and doesn't stop it from working. "Invalid Session" is what the problem is; you need a session ID. You might try:

```
sforce.connection.sessionId = "{!$Api.Session_ID}";
...
sforce.connection.create([record],{onSuccess: success, onFailure: failure});
```

Note that the page will run on the Public Site's profile permissions, so if their profile won't allow it, it won't work.